# Measuring coherence length with the Michelson Interferometer

Tags: optics, laser, interference, interferometry, coherence

In lab, I've been asked to measure the coherence length of a green-light laser source using a [Michelson Interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer). To do so, I configure the interferometer such that a circular fringe pattern with qualitatively maximal contrast is visible on a projection screen, then shift one mirror (mounted to a micrometer-advanced translating stage) forward and backward from that point until the contrast is significantly reduced. I'm told that the distance between these two points is half the coherence length ($L_c$). I then compare this to a coherence length measurement obtained via spectrometer (where $L_c = c\frac{1}{\Delta \nu}$, and where $\Delta \nu$ is the laser linewidth).

Unfortunately, while these formulae are quoted in numerous sources, I'm unable to find explanations or derivations. It is unclear to me why $L_c = c\frac{1}{\Delta\nu}$, and why the coherence length may be measured via the aforementioned interferometric procedure. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

A full answer involves Fourier analysis. I will describe the main idea without those mathematical details.

The frequency spread says, given that a given beam is not exactly monochromatic, what range of frequencies are contributing? This range is called the linewidth, $\Delta \nu$.

Now consider two oscillations, one at frequency $\nu$ and one at $\nu + \Delta \nu$. The wavelengths will be
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{c}{\nu},
\qquad
\lambda_2 = \frac{c}{\nu + \Delta \nu} .
$$

Now consider the combination of two waves with these wavelengths, propagating in the $x$ direction. If they are in phase at $x=0$, then as you go along the $x$ direction there will be $x/\lambda_1$ wavelengths of the first and $x/\lambda_2$ wavelengths of the second, in any given length $x$. The two waves therefore go out of phase at a value of $x$ where
$$
\frac{x}{\lambda_2} = \frac{x}{\lambda_1} + \frac{1}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
x \left( \frac{\nu + \Delta \nu}{c} - \frac{\nu}{c} \right) = \frac{1}{2}   
$$
Hence
$$
x = \frac{c}{2 \Delta \nu}.
$$
Your work with the Michelson is essentially measuring this $x$.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the previous answers, we reason qualitatively, without using Fourier analysis (which is not simple because we are dealing with random signals).

In this framework, the coherence length $L_c$ is the typical length over which we can consider that a beam is sinusoidal in space at a given moment. Likewise, we define the coherence time: time during which we can consider that an optical signal is sinusoidal at a given location.
In vacuum (or air), the relationship between the two is simple: $L_c = c \tau$.

So that the two signals which overlap after passing through the interferometer can give rise to interference, the time difference between the instants at which they were emitted must be less than the coherence time or even the difference between the paths traveled are less than the coherence length: $\delta=d_2-d_1<L_c$.
Schematically, we consider that we lose the fringes when $\delta=d_2-d_1=L_c$

If $e$ is the displacement of the mobile mirror relative to the optical contact we have $\delta=2e$. And therefore, if $e_{max}$ is the value for which the fringes disappear, we have $L_c=2 e_{max}$.

What you are measuring is precisely $2e_{max}$ since you are going on either side of the optical contact.

It remains to justify the relation $\Delta \nu = 1/ \tau$. We can already see that the relationship is homogeneous and reasonable: a purely sinusoidal signal, of zero spectral width, indeed has an infinite coherence duration. To go into a little more detail, we can consider sinusoids of the form $sin(2 \pi \nu t)$ and $sin(2 \pi (\nu + \Delta \nu) t)$: they are in phases at time $0$ but the phase shift increases with time. It remains negligible as long as $2 \pi \Delta \nu t \ll 2 \pi$ or $t \ll 1/\Delta \nu$. As expected,we find the coherence time $1/\Delta \nu$. But this is only qualitative.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score -1):

For a laser the coherence length is a measure of how pure the beam is in its color.  For a perfect (not possible!) green beam at say 450nm wavelength we would have infinite coherence length (also not possible).

Let's say we have an imperfect 1u laser, if it was perfect it would lase at the 1um only but for arguments sake let's say the laser is actually lasing at at 1um and another spike at 1.1um (say 50/50).  In this example it's very easy to calculate 1/delta v times c.  When we use an actual laser we get a normal distribution of emitted wavelengths ... I believe the spectrometer just uses 1 sigma std deviation for its coherence length calculation.

For the above example if you used an interferometer you would find the most perfect interference occurs when 10 wavelengths of the 1.1um emission match up to 11 of the 1um emissions.  This occurs every 11um. To get the worst contrast ... maybe it occurs at 5.5nm in this simple example.

For a real laser beam we never get perfect interference ... there is just too many wavelengths at varying intensities  ... for the coherence length we just assume that it is related to the distance between best and worst patterns.